# Is it possible to compile .tex files to PDF with 'pandoc'?

Tags: macos, pdf, pandoc, tex

Is it possible to compile a .tex file with pandoc?

I'm currently taking my class notes in MultiMarkdown with MacVim. That way, when I get home, I can just `mmd2tex` and compile the .tex file to PDF using TexShop. It works great but the process is actually quite time consuming.

I'd like to know if there would be a way to achieve virtually the same thing using `pandoc` from the command line. I tried to convert my original .txt file directly to PDF with `pandoc` but I'm getting all sort of errors...

Anyone have a solution for this? Or maybe suggesting another workflow for notetaking?

Comment: @SoumyaR please don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you just want to convert a `.tex` file to PDF you don't need `pandoc`, it's better to use a LaTeX processor directly (instead of using pandoc which will call pdflatex in turn, but will pass along only a subset of all LaTeX commands):

```
pdflatex test.tex
```

To create a [PDF from markdown](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf), pandoc is the right tool. It also uses LaTeX under the hood by default:

```
pandoc test.md -o test.pdf
```

Comment: Note that this will work for latex to pdf conversion too e.g.,: `pandoc samplefile.tex -o test.pdf`

Comment: And it work better with pandoc by default if you have no knowledge of tex

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa I updated my answer to make it more clear why in 99% of the cases you should call pdflatex instead of pandoc when going from .tex to pdf.